# Capturing Splunk dashboards to PDF

Tags: pdf, splunk, cutycapt

I want to capture the Splunk dashboard to a pdf for sending a periodic email. The inbuilt pdf generator doesn't creates a good pdf in Splunk. Is there any open source tools that can be used like CutyCapt which can capture the screen via linux commands for pages with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could try [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

It uses WebKit internally and has a [screen capture](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) capability allowing you to export web page to PNG/JPEG/PDF.